# Why does my "Answers" summary in my activity page show green even if the accepted answer is not mine?

Tags: bug

I was looking at my summary activity page and noticed the last answer sorted by "newest" appeared green as if the accepted answer was mine:

[image]

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70490239/is-there-a-way-to-do-something-like-insert-into-where-in-mysql-node-js/70490977#70490977) have an accepted answer, but it's not the one I've posted, so does it appear green because it has an accepted answer or wasn't it supposed to?

Comment: I believe the green color means that the question has an accepted answer, and that this is not related to if that was for your answer or someone else's answer.